# How do I get argc and argv while debugging C using gdb in Windows?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gdb

I have the following program named `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("%d\n", argc);
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    
}
```

I want to debug this with `gdb` using Visual Studio Code. I have installed the `C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing`.

I open the folder where `test.c` is located and Visual Studio Code generates `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

and `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

When I click on "Terminal > Run Build Task" the program is succesfully compiled.

If I go to a terminal (cmd) I get:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\Test>test.exe foo bar baz
4
test.exe
foo
bar
baz
```

So far so good.

I modify `tasks.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I launch the program using "Run > Run Without debugging" I can see that there are the 4 parameters expected (command + 3 parameters). Again, so far, so good.

However, if I launch the program using "Run > Start debugging" I can not see any output in Visual Studio Code and inspecting argv only shows the .exe file.

What shall I do to specify some command line arguments while debugging with gdb in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Without any further experience with VSC (for me it's little more than an expanded editor, not a real IDE), but with some with GDB: The arguments that you gave are given to GDB. You need to add another setup command for GDB, for example "set args ...", see its documentation. The look up of the correct syntax is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: I am aware on the set args gdb command, the problem is how to incorporate that into VS Code. 
Just in case somebody reads the message and is facing the same issue I finally found that if I include `"externalConsole": false,` the outputs from stdout and stderr are incorporated normally into the external window which is launched while debugging. The list of arguments specified in launch.json are also normally passed towards gdb. 
Still do not know how to handle everything within VS Code embedded terminal windows but the above workaround seems to be good enough.

Comment: Do you see that JSON array `setupCommands`? Add another command. (You need to know JSON syntax for this. There are plenty of hits in the web.)